# Как убрать белый фон под иконкой?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как убрать белую строку там где иконки увеличить, уменьшить и один к одному?
И почему он там появляется?
Т.е. под иконкой откуда-то берется белый фон по всей ширине блока, но он не нужен.
Иконки должны быть прямо на фотографии

```css
.acatpicdiv {border:1px solid #000; width:100%; height:300px; overflow:hidden; }
.acatpicinnerdiv {position:relative; }
.acatpic {cursor:move;}

.acatpiclablediv {position:absolute; border:1px solid #000; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; cursor:pointer;background-color: white;}

.selected-tr td {background: #dedfe0;}

.zoom-in {cursor: pointer;}
.zoom-out {cursor: pointer;}
.zoom-out {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.panzoom/3.2.2/jquery.panzoom.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="acatpicdiv">
    <img class="zoom-in" src="https://png.icons8.com/dusk/24/000000/zoom-in.png" title="Увеличить масштаб" width="24">
    <img class="zoom-out" src="https://png.icons8.com/dusk/24/000000/zoom-out.png" title="Уменьшить масштаб" width="24">
    <img class="zoom-out" src="https://png.icons8.com/dusk/24/000000/zoom-to-actual-size.png" title="сбросить" width="24">

    <div class="parent" >
      <div class="panzoom acatpicinnerdiv ui-widget-content" id="draggable">
        <img src="https://otvet.imgsmail.ru/download/4e0ce039dd5c81fb86558fdb3df75d9c_h-2.jpg" >

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var $section = $('section').first();
      $section.find('.panzoom').panzoom({
        $zoomIn: $section.find(".zoom-in"),
        $zoomOut: $section.find(".zoom-out"),
        $zoomRange: $section.find(".zoom-range"),
        $reset: $section.find(".reset")
      });
    })();
  </script>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обернул кнопки в `div` с классом `button-wrapper` с абсолютным позиционированием, и перенес кнопки ниже, чем картинка, чтобы отображалось сверху.

```css
.acatpicdiv {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.acatpicinnerdiv {
  position: relative;
}

.acatpic {
  cursor: move;
}

.acatpiclablediv {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
}

.selected-tr td {
  background: #dedfe0;
}

.zoom-in {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.zoom-out {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.zoom-out {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.panzoom/3.2.2/jquery.panzoom.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="acatpicdiv">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="panzoom acatpicinnerdiv ui-widget-content" id="draggable">
        <img src="https://otvet.imgsmail.ru/download/4e0ce039dd5c81fb86558fdb3df75d9c_h-2.jpg">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <img class="zoom-in" src="https://png.icons8.com/dusk/24/000000/zoom-in.png" title="Увеличить масштаб" width="24">
      <img class="zoom-out" src="https://png.icons8.com/dusk/24/000000/zoom-out.png" title="Уменьшить масштаб" width="24">
      <img class="zoom-out" src="https://png.icons8.com/dusk/24/000000/zoom-to-actual-size.png" title="сбросить" width="24">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var $section = $('section').first();
      $section.find('.panzoom').panzoom({
        $zoomIn: $section.find(".zoom-in"),
        $zoomOut: $section.find(".zoom-out"),
        $zoomRange: $section.find(".zoom-range"),
        $reset: $section.find(".reset")
      });
    })();
  </script>
</section>
```